# How to save text font (which was set up manually) with a text in C#

Tags: c#

I set up the font manually for the labels, however, when I am saving it as a Word Document the font which I set up previously disappears. I do not know how to figure it out

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = label1.Text + textBox1.Text + "\r\n\r\n\r\n" +
                      label2.Text + textBox2.Text + "\r\n\r\n\r\n";

        sSaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Microsoft Word| *.doc";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = sfd.FileName;
            MessageBox.Show(path);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(text);

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The string data type doesn't have font support. You're just saving out plain text, not an actual word document.

Comment: You are **not** saving it “as a Word Document”. You are merely using a file name which ends in `.doc`. But that’s just an arbitrary convention – you’re not using the actual Word document file format.

Answer (score 1):

[StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) (basically) writes a string (of characters) to a file. Word formatting is not that simple. If you want the formatting then it gets more complicated.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8b7k14a4.aspx) for more info on formatting Word documents. You need an object that can control the document.